# Orange3 installation with pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, orange

I have been trying to install orange3 on my Linux machine. Upon trying:

```
pip3 install orange3
```

I get this verbos error:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting orange3
  Using cached Orange3-3.27.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting AnyQt>=0.0.11
  Downloading AnyQt-0.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Collecting baycomp>=1.0.2
  Using cached baycomp-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from orange3) (20.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.23.0,>=0.22.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from orange3) (0.22.1)
...
Collecting orange-widget-base>=4.8.1
  Using cached orange_widget_base-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
...
Collecting python-louvain>=0.13
  Using cached python-louvain-0.14.tar.gz (19 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_us67ap2/python-louvain/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_us67ap2/python-louvain/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-t2a936sw
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_us67ap2/python-louvain/
    Complete output (28 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2455, in resolve
        return functools.reduce(getattr, self.attrs, module)
    AttributeError: type object 'Distribution' has no attribute '_finalize_feature_opts'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_us67ap2/python-louvain/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        scripts=['bin/community']
...
        raise ImportError(str(exc)) from exc
    ImportError: type object 'Distribution' has no attribute '_finalize_feature_opts'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have already tried updating pip as well as setup-tools using

pip install --upgrade pip

etc but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a too old version of the `setuptools` package. Try upgrading it (and pip as well, while you're at it): `python3 -m pip install setuptools pip`.

Here's a link to a setuptools issue describing the problem: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2029

Comment: It seems like it's actually the `python-louvain` package that's failing. What happens if you install that package by itself? Also, can you reproduce this in a fresh virtualenv? `python3 -m venv test_env && source test_env/bin/activate && python3 -m pip install orange3`

Comment: Looking at the issue I linked to, it could also be a problem that the requirements of orange3 include `setuptools` itself: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/blob/master/requirements-core.txt